# Spock add mock element to a SortedSet

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a Spy for an instance of a domain class `ProjectSegmentCategory`, which contains a SortedSet of instances of another domain class `ProjectSegmentCategoryValue`. As the two domain classes are both quite complex and have a lot of dependencies, I want to mock both as Mock or Spy.

My problem is, that I don't know, how to add a Spy/Mock to a SortedSet. From the error I get, I look like when I want to add the object to the SortedSet, it tries to create a new object with a Copy constructor and this fails, because the original object is a Spy.

So my question is, how can I add a Spock Spy to a Set?

This is my code:

```
class ProjectSegmentCategoryGsonSpec extends Specification implements JsonViewTest {

  // Define the spy objects needed for the test
  def projectsegmentcategory = Spy(ProjectSegmentCategory);
  def librarycategory = Spy(LibrarySegmentCategory);
  def projectsegmentcategoryvalue = Spy(ProjectSegmentCategoryValue)
  Set<ProjectSegmentCategoryValue> projectsegmentcategoryvalues;
  def projectsegmentclassification = Spy(ProjectSegmentClassification)

  def librarycategoryvalue = Spy(LibrarySegmentCategoryValue)

  def setup() {

    // Set attributes of the objects for the test
    projectsegmentcategory.id = 1;
    projectsegmentcategory.hasData = true;
    projectsegmentcategory.isClustered = true;
    projectsegmentcategory.isUnlockedForBudgetingModule = true;

    librarycategory.id = 1;
    projectsegmentcategory.librarycategory = librarycategory;

    def projectsegmentcategoryvalues_list = [projectsegmentcategoryvalue]
    projectsegmentcategory.projectsegmentcategoryvalues = new TreeSet<ProjectSegmentCategoryValue>();
    projectsegmentcategory.projectsegmentcategoryvalues.add(Mock(ProjetSegmentCategoryValue))

    projectsegmentcategory.projectsegmentcategoryvalues.first().id = 1
    projectsegmentcategoryvalue.isClustered = true
    projectsegmentcategoryvalue.isUnlockedForBudgetingModule = true
    librarycategoryvalue.id = 1
    projectsegmentcategoryvalue.projectsegmentcategory = projectsegmentcategory
    projectsegmentcategoryvalue.librarycategoryvalue = librarycategoryvalue

    projectsegmentclassification.id = 1
    projectsegmentcategory.projectsegmentclassification = projectsegmentclassification
}

void "Test ProjectSegmentCategory Gson with default values"() {

    when:"A ProjectSegmentCategory gson is rendered"
    def renderResult = render(template: "/project/instance/projectSegmentCategory/projectSegmentCategory", model:[projectsegmentcategory: projectsegmentcategory])

    then:"The json is correct"
    // Mock the method getName as the real method is more complicate and requires a Language object
    2 * projectsegmentcategory.getName(_ as String) >> "Test"
    2 * projectsegmentcategory.getName() >> "Test"
    2 * projectsegmentcategory.toString() >> "Test"
    2 * projectsegmentcategoryvalue.getName(_ as String) >> "Test"
    1 * projectsegmentcategoryvalue.getTranslationByLanguageId(_ as Long) >> "Test"
    1 * projectsegmentcategoryvalue.getId() >> "1"
    //1 * ProjectSegmentCategoryValue.getTranslationByLanguageId(_ as Long) >> "Test"
    1 * projectsegmentcategory.projectsegmentcategoryvalues.iterator(_) >> projectsegmentcategoryvalue.iterator()

    // Tests
    renderResult.json.id == 1
    renderResult.json.isClustered == true
    renderResult.json.isUnlockedForBudgetingModule == true
    renderResult.json.librarycategoryvalue.id == 1
    renderResult.json.projectsegmentcategory.id == 1
    renderResult.json.name == "Test"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error message and the code of your domain classes. Furthermore, you should avoid using nested spies/mocks if possible. And you probably would need to mock the `compareTo` method otherwise the mock will return `null` or `0` which would replace the other value.

Comment: try using  `metaClass`